Having issues with running Android VM on Android Studio
On a fresh install of Android Studio, I configured a basic Pixel Fold VM on Android API 35. When I ran it, I was greeted with an adrupt termination of the VM
(The emulator process for AVD Pixel_Fold_API_35 has terminated.)
followed by the following written to the log file:
2024-08-26 19:14:33,471 [1459177]   
INFO - Emulator: Pixel Fold API 35 - [16944:16276:20240826,191433.471:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130]
GetFileAttributes

C:\Users\Ibrahim\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\10072829-5909-488a-9a81-4a5de635d5a6: 
The system cannot find the file specified. (2)

I attempted to recreate the file, but I was unaware of its contents.

We had a similar issue utilizing Ubuntu; fortunately, it's an easy fix.
The problem lies in the fact the appropriate google files aren't downloaded.

In the Android-Studio application goto file and click settings.

Scroll down and click Android SDK.
Next to Android SDK Licenses click Edit.
Ensure both Android SDK and Android SDK Platform are checked and click Next to run through the wizard. If you run into similar issues that we did where the boxes are uncheckable then check whatever box is checkable and click next to go through the wizard. Also, be sure your android sdk files and folders are in the right place at this time; usually by default, they are where they're suppose to be unless you did something weird or did some sort of custom install; in which case simply put the path to where your directory is.

In the same settings window, ensure both android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) and Android Emulator are checked and press Apply and OK. (If Android Emulator is unchecked the Android Emulator hasn't been downloaded. That's part of the issue or problem that needs to be fixed.)


If all the sdk stuff and emulator junk is checked and downloaded then close or cancel out of the settings window and click the little rectangular icon that looks like a phone with the android head next to the rectangle to open the Device Manager. This is located on the far right side of the screen in the navbar. When hovering the pointer of the mouse over the symbols text appears to show what that icon symbol is.

When the Device Manager Tab Window opens in the Workspace click the little plus '+'   button at the top of the Device Manager tab screen called Add New Device.

Select Create Virtual Device from the drop down Menu.
Select the appropriate hardware to emulate when the Virtual Device Configuration window menu pops up and click Next.
The necessary components should download and install if they aren't already.
There you can name the emulator and all that for the specifics of the project.
In our case we selected Medium Phone and titled the emulator 'Android Phone Emulator' without the quotes.

Click the play button, and it should function as normally as expected. Note: If it's the first time running that emulator or if it's a large build anticipate running the emulator to operate a little slower, and it should be faster on future runs after everything runs for the first time and does it's thing. Such is also dependent on system specs of the machine, the operating system, and hardware capabilities and other such parameters android studio is operating on. Other softwares and background tasks also effects performance and speed as well.

Hopefully, this works.
